# Update ViewModel property from task

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am building an app with WPF and Caliburn.Micro. I want to update a ProgressBar from an Task/Thread and I am wondering what I need to correctly update the UI:

```
public class DemoViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private int m_Progress;

    public int Progress
    {
        get { return m_Progress; }
        set
        {
            if (value == m_Progress) return;
            m_Progress = value;

            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(CanStart));
        }
    }

    public bool CanStart => Progress == 0 || Progress == 100;

    public void Start()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(example);
    }

    private void example()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Progress = i + 1; // this triggers PropertChanged-Event and leads to the update of the UI
            Thread.Sleep(20);
        }
    }
}
```

From other programming languages I know that I need to synchronize with the UI thread to update the UI but my code just works. Is there something I missed and which could cause sporadic errors or is there some magic behind the scenes which care of the synchronization?

Comment: INPC events are automatically marshalled onto the UI thread, so you don't have to worry.  But... if you update the UI every 20 bloody milliseconds (Thread.Sleep(20)!!!!!!!) you won't see jack in the UI because it will be too busy working to actually update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will depend on how you've implemented INotifyPropertyChanged. The implementation should delgate all UI updates to the appropriate dispatcher.

Sample Implementation:

```
public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string name) {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
```

Also to clean up the task start a bit:

**Edit:**
Removed unnecessary bool return value, and set `ConfigureAwait` to stay off UI thread when task completes.

```
public async void Start()
{
    await Task.Run(() => example()).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private async Task example()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Progress = i + 1; // this triggers PropertChanged-Event and leads to the update of the UI
        await Task.Delay(20);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I checked the source code of Caliburn.Micro and if you derive the ViewModel from PropertyChangedBase then synchronization is done by Caliburn.Micro. There is a handy Execute helper class in CM for synchronization I learned too.

Comment: What's the advantage of using await/async in this context? The method example() doesn't have a return value but you need one for Task I guess.

Comment: @Ragna There's several ways to go about that. You could probably get by with just returning a task. Really I just wanted to loose the blocking `Thread.Sleep`. See edit.